# latex input to html and pdf output

Tags: html, ruby, pdf, latex

Is there a ruby gem that can parse latex formatted string to html string and pdf binary string including bibtex bibliography?

I'm using textile (redcloth) right now in my rails app to get formated html, but I'd like to use latex to do it. I also would like to use *.bib file for references. And having latex it should also be easy to build a pdf file, in order to provide a pdf version of the same article (nice to have)...

I also could do it with the system call and e.g. texlive, but then I've to save the user input to file and manage these files and put it back to database and that all would take some time. I don't like this approach...

Is there a nice way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [runtex](http://rubygems.org/gems/runtex/versions/0.2.1), although I do not know if it will do exactly what you want, I have not tested it.

Comment: not quite the solution, but gives a nice direction to look at and simplifies the procedure I've got now. Thanks